# How to integrate juju-gui into openstack horizon dashboard?

Tags: juju, openstack

I saw this video:

https://www.openstack.org/summit/tokyo-2015/videos/presentation/canonical-the-juju-app-store-for-your-openstack

Which talks about juju plug-in for openstack horizon dashboard. The author of the talk told that everything we see there can be found on line. I searched for the juju horizon plug in on the Internet but failed to find anything.

Can anybody help me integrating juju gui into an openstack horizon dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in Juju in Horizon! We demonstrated this to gauge interest and the Horizon plugin relies on code that was not completed to production grade. If you're interested please send an email to the address at the end of the presentation and folks at Canonical will get back with you and know that there's more interest for this idea.